# Oracle SQL Convert to Join Operator Style

Tags: oracle, join

The query works, but I was asked to rewrite it in join operator style.

```
SELECT pr.ProdName, pr.ProdPrice
FROM Product pr, OrderTbl ord, OrdLine ol, Customer cu
WHERE pr.ProdNo=ol.ProdNo
AND ord.OrdNo=ol.OrdNo
AND cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo
AND cu.CustNo='C2388597'
AND ord.OrdDate BETWEEN '01-Jan-04' AND '31-Jan-04';
```

I've just started out using Oracle, so I'm not sure how. I think I should be using INNER JOINS, but I don't know exactly how. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Watch out for implicit date formats.  `'01-Jan-04'` will not always work, depending on your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT and NLS_LANGUAGE.  It's safer to use ANSI date literals, like `date '2004-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitly read about [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) though, but here is how this cross join style can be converted to inner join

```
SELECT pr.ProdName, pr.ProdPrice
FROM Product pr
 INNER JOIN OrdLine ol ON pr.ProdNo=ol.ProdNo
 INNER JOIN OrderTbl ord ON ord.OrdNo = ol.OrdNo
 INNER JOIN Customer cu ON cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo 
WHERE cu.CustNo='C2388597'
AND ord.OrdDate BETWEEN '01-Jan-04' AND '31-Jan-04';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got this error: ERROR at line 5: 
ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: @Cyrallia glad I can help, don't forget to mark the correct answer for future reference :)

Comment: I don't know why people call this cross join style. There is definitely no cross join going on here.

Comment: @ElectricLlama this is an implicit cross join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: This is not an implicit cross join as all of the tables are joined in the where clause. Your information is completely incorrect. If there were no joins in the where clause then yes it would be an implicit cross join. This has the exact same function as if the OP had used INNER JOIN, just a different syntax. Take a look at the query plan - it would be identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pr.ProdName, pr.ProdPrice
FROM Product pr
 INNER JOIN OrdLine ol ON pr.ProdNo=ol.ProdNo
 INNER JOIN OrderTbl ord ON ord.OrdNo = ol.OrdNo
 INNER JOIN Customer cu ON cu.CustNo=ord.CustNo
WHERE cu.CustNo='C2388597'
AND ord.OrdDate BETWEEN '01-Jan-04' AND '31-Jan-04';
```

[Here is for you to read on `Joins`:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).